# mingw32 make: ***no rule to make target 'win32' stop

Tags: makefile, mingw, codeblocks, command-prompt, glfw

I am installing glfw forcodeblocks, when I try to execute the makefile through command prompt in order to compil glfw using this command:mingw32-make win32-mingw I get the following error  mingw32 make: ***no rule to make target 'win32'. stop.

I am running a 64 bit version of windows 8

Comment: Please look at my answer . you must use CMake **not mingw32-make**

Comment: How far you come with `CMake` ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

For newer versions of glfw you can not use `compile.bat` or command **mingw32-make win32-mingw**

You must use **CMake** to create makefiles under the source folder e.g. build folder.
Then you can run `mingw32-make` .

---

For older versions :

Try it with the command described on the glfw side.

Unzip the archive anywhere you like (I will assume C:\glfw for simplicity).

**Compile:**

For Windows users, there is a batch file which allows to compile using a variety of compilers.

Open a DOS window, cd to the directory where GLFW lives (e.g. C:\glfw), and type

```
compile make mgw
```

[Building the Libraries](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_GLFW_with_Code::Blocks)

As you can see there is a `compile.bat`

[image]

Of course you have to `cd` to your source folder. From an folder outside the source a `compile.bat` will not work.

if in your source there is no compile download it here.

[glfw-2.5.zip](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/glfw/glfw-2.5.zip?download)

Comment: compile is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: When I download the glfw 2.5 that you have provided there is a compile. bat but when I download the current version there isn't- is the current version compiled differently, I get my version from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/glfw/?source=dlp